# Intersect function is generating different outputs in ArcMap and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, intersection, intersect

I am currently running the following code in ArcPy:

```
in_dir_temp = "D:\\X\\"
x1= in_dir_temp + "x1.shp"
x2= in_dir_temp + "x2.shp"
y1= in_dir_temp + "y1.shp"
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([x1, x2], y1, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```

Where x1 and x2 are polygons and so is y1.

When running this in ArcPy, it does not generate a shapefile in the output. It only generates .sbn .xml and .sbx files, despite the code outputting

```
<Result 'D:\\X\\y1.shp'>
```

However when I manually intersect the two polygons in ArcMap, it generates a polygon and shapefile.

I can't figure out why I am getting two different outputs?

Comment: @BERA sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue.

I put the out in a geodb and it seemed work.

My new code is:

```
in_dir_temp = "D:\\X\\"
x1= in_dir_temp + "x1.shp"
x2= in_dir_temp + "x2.shp"
y1= in_dir_temp + "Default.gdb\\y1.shp"
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([x1, x2], y1, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```